# drop and create back to back in one script not working -TOAD

Tags: sql, toad

AS far as I know, DDL commands have an implicit commit with 'em. I am trying to drop a sequence and then 
create a same named sequence in TOAD but it doesn't execute fully. The drop command works fine, thus halting before `create` command.

```
drop sequence rep_seq;

CREATE SEQUENCE rep_seq
MINVALUE 100
START WITH 107
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

IS this a TOAD issue or something else ?

Comment: It should work just fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5376c/1

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your command as a script (with <kbd>F5</kbd>) instead of executing it as a statement (with <kbd>F9</kbd>)